# Creating custom avatars

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, avatar

I'm starting a project that will require that users be able to create multiple custom avatars. To do this, I want them to be able to send images that are in their inventory to a manipulation frame. Within this frame, users should be able to move and resize the images - double clicking them to remove the image from the frame and sending it back into their inventory. To the right of the manipulation frame, I would like a sortable list that will dictate the z-index of the corresponding item with the item at the top being in back of the manipulation frame. So far, I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/Thaikhan/e3Gd6/10/show/.

The list generates and is sortable but does not affect the z-index of the image. Also, the code is pretty buggy and often images will disappear off frame.

See JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Thaikhan/e3Gd6/10/

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
//Click into Frame
$('.inventory').on('click', 'img', function () {
$(this).resizable({
    aspectRatio: 1,
    autoHide: true,
    containment: "parent",
    minHeight: 50,
    minWidth: 50
});

$(this).parent().appendTo(".frame").draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    cursor: "move"
});

refreshIndexList();
});

//Double Click out of Frame
$('.frame').on('dblclick', '.ui-draggable', function () {
    $(this).appendTo(".inventory");
    $(this).draggable("destroy");
    $("img", this).resizable("destroy").attr('style', '');
    refreshIndexList();
});

//Updates List Items
function refreshIndexList() {
    var listitems = $('.frame').children().length;
    $('#sortable').empty();
    var titles = $(".frame img:nth-of-type(1)").attr('title');
    for (var count = 1; count <= listitems; count++) {
        var title = $(".frame img").eq(count-1).attr('title');
        var $li = $("<li class='ui-state-default'/>").text(title);
        $('#sortable').append($li);
    }
}

//Makes List Sortable
$(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    });
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});

//Inventory Grid
$(function() {
    $( "#grid" ).sortable();
    $( "#grid" ).disableSelection();
});
```

I am a novice in JavaScript and have received much help in getting this far. I am hoping that once again I can receive help from the community and figure out how to have the sortable list change the z-index of the item. Additionally, if anyone sees why it's buggy, please let me know.

Ultimately, I want to be able to grab from the manipulation frame the image_id's, their locations, their z-indices, and their sizes and store it all in a database. This will hopefully allow users to return and edit their avatar creations.

A thousand thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create function with editing z-index:

```
function zindex() {
    var title = ""; 
    var i = 9999;
    $(".ui-state-default").each(function () {
        i--; //z-index position counter
        title = $(this).text(); 
        $(".frame img[title='" + title + "']").parent().css("z-index", i);
    });
}
```

call it on adding img

```
$('.inventory').on('click', 'img', function () {
    $(this).resizable({
        aspectRatio: 1,
        autoHide: true,
        containment: "parent",
        minHeight: 50,
        minWidth: 50
    });

    $(this).parent().appendTo(".frame").draggable({
        containment: "parent",
        cursor: "move"
    });

    refreshIndexList();
    zindex();
});
```

and use it on mouseup (drop event emulation)

```
$("#sortable").mouseup(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
    zindex();}, 100);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/raskalbass/cTSjn/)

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you so much raskalbass! Do you happen to have any idea why the images tend to shoot up and out of sight when I dbl-click them?

Comment: What exactly you are doing when it happens? I can't trigger this

Comment: I'm using chrome. If I click all of the images into frame, then move them all to the center so they overlap, then double-click the top image, almost without fail the others move upward.

Comment: Any luck triggering the moving images?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know, looks like it is jquery-ui bug. Sorry, but I don't have enough time to found core of this problem.